# Enviar imagen desde android a servidor web api

Tags: android

Necesito ayuda por favor.
Estoy intentando hacer un post de una imagen desde android studio a un web api en .NET pero no estoy logrando hacerlo.
Eh probado con algunos codigos en internet pero todos son muy distintos, y los que probe no logre que funcione.
El resto de las llamadas REST las hago con volley.
Alguien me podria ayudar con este tema con algun codigo de ejemplo probado, no importa con que libreria?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Volley podría ser tu solución. Mira este tutorial en español: http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/02/android-volley-peticiones-http/

Comment: Perdon que levante este tema pero tengo el mismo problema, lo pudiste solucionar?

Answer (score 1):

Transforma tu imagen a Base 64 y envía el texto como un post normal

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap image BitmapFactory.decodeFile("tu/ruta/de/foto.jpg", options);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos);
byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
String base64 Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: ya pobre esa opcion pero no funciona, la variable que contiene el string llega vacia. Nose si sera por el tamaño.

Comment: si fuera por el tamaño daría error en el servidor, estas enviando todo bien y recibiéndolo bien en el servidor?

Trata de ver el log de la petición en android para verificar que si se envía